# can't login magento in local system in firefox

Tags: cookies, magento, localhost, admin

I have installed magento in my local Xampp. After installing I have tried to login in Mozilla (both in front end and admin side). Does any one know how to login magento in fire fox.

Thanks

Comment: Just defending this question, while it might not look programming related, it actually is... refer to answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, and a number of blog posts document some solutions.  Try Ash's [solution](http://www.aschroder.com/2009/05/fixing-magento-login-problem-after-a-fresh-installation/) first, failing that you need to alter Magento's code per Richard's [post](http://mysillypointofview.richardferaro.com/2010/03/24/how-to-fix-magentos-admin-login-failing-no-error-message-on-localhost/).  Make sure that you follow his instructions to move the code into your `/app/code/local` to prevent future upgrade issues.

The problem occurs because of the way that Firefox handles cookies from localhost, and Magento's code is not very forgiving of that.

HTH,
JD

Comment: I'm getting a malware alert for the second link (Richard's post).

Answer (score 0):

Safari worked for me without any workarounds.